# Listen to click on button in listview

Tags: java, android, listview, button, adapter

I have a fragment with a listview in it.
The listview uses a custom adapter. Each item in the listview contains a button.
What I need is for the activity to know what button I press in the listview. I need this because the fragment needs too send a message to its activity depending on what button is pressed. So basically I want the `OnClickListener` to be in the fragment and not in the adapter.

I have tried to get the buttons from the list by itterating over all its elements and do a getChild(), but it does not react on click.

```
Button theButton = (Button)theListView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.button_id);
```

I have also tried with the getView on the adapter.

```
Button theButton = (Button) adapter.getView(i, null, null).findViewById(R.id.button_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the OnClickListener in the Adapter as usual but keep a reference to your fragment!

Let us say that your fragment class is MyFragment. Pass your fragment to the adapter; -i.e. in the constructor

```
private MyFragment theFragment;
public YourAdapter(MyFragment f) {
    this.theFragment = f;
}
```

In this way you can use `theFragment` in every OnClickListener you set.